# Boot from old hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-10, ssd, raid

The motherboard of my old computer died suddenly and so I bought a new computer. It has two 1TB HDDs on RAID 0 and comes preinstalled with Windows 10 Home. I wanted my computer to boot from my old 120GB SSD from my old computer but it doesn't seem to recognize it as boot drive. It was working perfectly with my old computer.

I can view files from the SSD and so this confirms that it is working. The boot partition is marked active.

I tried changing the boot hard drive in the bios but in the bios, the only two options shown in the boot menu are

- Windows Boot Manager (Intel Volume1)
- CD/DVDRW

After searching online, a website suggested swapping the Sata of the old hard drive with that of the new one. I tried even this but this didn't work either. It gave me the error "boot disk not found" and in the boot menu, the only option was "CD/DVDRW".

For Reference :
Motherboard : ASUS Z170 PRO GAMING
All Hard Drives Run GPT.

Any other solutions?

Comment: Depending on the age of your old computer your hard disk may be formatted MBR. Windows only supported booting from MBR on old BIOS based systems and chances are your new mobo is UEFI based, on which windows only supports booting from GPT disks. There are some tools to convert MBR to GPT for this purpose out there, but I don't know how well they work.

Comment: Yeah, my old hard drive was formatted with MBR...let me try changing it to GPT.

Comment: @Mokubai Converted to GPT and that doesn't work.

Comment: it won't work. just extract your files by using a hiren disk and then format and use it again.

Comment: @ErdemEce good luck doing that on a raid 0 set of disks.

Comment: [this](http://scottiestech.info/2015/11/12/fix-uefi-bios-boot-problems-on-a-new-motherboard/) may be useful